# Where is the documentation for removing Oauth from Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I know OAuth is now supported by Spring Security, so I want to review the official documentation so that I know how to safely remove it from my project.

However, when I go to the [official site page for this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/site/docs/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/), many links like "Tutorial" or "User Guide" are broken.

Is this just a temporary bug with the vendor site or is there some other location I should go to for the official documentation on that topic?

Comment: I don't understand why this question got closed. It's not asking for recommendation, it's asking how to find documentation.

Comment: I agree; Shog (a former CM) once said that requests for the official documentation location of a tech is a fine, on-topic question to ask here; the "off-site resource request" reason is intended for recommendation-esque (read: opinionated) questions, instead. I've voted to reopen this, but can't guarantee it will ultimately get reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Parent level link to the documentation is here
https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth#learn

Here is the developer guide for OAuth 1.0 & OAuth 2
https://spring-projects.github.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/devguide.html

Comment: I have seen it but is that all? Other projects like Spring security has huge reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/index.html